# 406 Not Acceptable Spring Rest WS

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc

I am writing a spring rest WS to return response as XML. Below are my classes and pom file.

I am getting Http 406 Error on executing the service as below:

```
 http://localhost:8080/SpringRestExample/rest/emp/dummy.xml
```

However, I am getting the JSON response back when executing

```
http://localhost:8080/SpringRestExample/rest/emp/dummy.json
```

Please advise

pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

EmployeeController:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/emp/dummy", method = RequestMethod.GET,produces={"application/xml"})
public @ResponseBody Employee getDummyEmployeeXML() {
    logger.info("Start getDummyEmployee");
    Employee emp = new Employee();
    emp.setId(9999);
    emp.setName("Dummy");
    emp.setCreatedDate(new Date());
    empData.put(9999, emp);
    return emp;
}
```

app-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.skanda.spring.controller" />

  <beans:bean id="contentNegotiationManager"
         class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
<beans:property name="favorPathExtension" value="true" />
<beans:property name="favorParameter" value="true" />
<beans:property name="parameterName" value="mediaType" />
<beans:property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="true"/>
<beans:property name="useJaf" value="false"/>
<beans:property name="defaultContentType" value="application/json" />

<beans:property name="mediaTypes">
    <beans:map>
        <beans:entry key="json" value="application/json" />
        <beans:entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
   </beans:map>
</beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

Employee:

```
public class Employee implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = -7788619177798333712L;

private int id;
private String name;
private Date createdDate;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@JsonSerialize(using=DateSerializer.class)
public Date getCreatedDate() {
    return createdDate;
}
public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
    this.createdDate = createdDate;
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

406 means that the server is not able to produce a response in the content type asked by the client. Check the Accept header of your HTTP request, and make sure it contains application/xml.

Maybe it contains text/xml, and that's what you should use in the `produces`attribute of your `@RequestMapping`annotation. BTW, you should use the constants in `org.springframework.http.MediaType` instead of hard-coding the string as you're doing.

Comment: Thank you JB. I added the accept header and when executed again i am getting 400 Http Error(The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect ())

Comment: Should I need to pass any other header than accept in request. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

for any type of xml conversion you need to add @XmlRootElement annotation on top of Model class. i have done the changes and run the above program and got the result.Just add @XmlRootElement above Employee class and you are done.

Comment: This should be comment